# Inspecionar aplicativo do safari não esta identificando aplicativo nativo

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, safari, webkit

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo usando a plataforma Cordova e estava usando o modo desenvolvedor do Safari para debugar e inspecionar os elementos do app no iPhone. Mas depois que atualizei meu iPhone para versão 16.4 o modo de inspecionar do Safari parou de reconhecer os aplicativos.
Quando estava usando versão do iPhone 16.1.1 estava funcionando a função inspecionar, somente depois que atualizei que parou.
Tentei voltar a versão do iPhone para a 16.1.1 mas essa versão não é mais assinada pela Apple por isso não permite voltar a versão do iPhone.
Atualizei tanto a versão do meu Mac quanto do meu Xcode para ver se era alguma incompatibilidade das versões mas não resolveu.
Quando abro algum site no Safari do celular consigo inspecionar normalmente só quando é aplicativo que não consigo.
Quando tento no simulador do Xcode também não esta funcionando, acredito que seja alguma configuração.

Estou usando:

- iPhone XR versão 16.4.1 ;
- MacOs Ventura versão 13.3.1 ;
- Xcode versão 14.3(14E222b;
- Cordova versão 11.1.0
- Plataforma Cordova versão 6.2.0

Comment: nao compreendi muito bem, poderia deixar a parte mais contextualizada?

Comment: Consegui  encontrar a solução do problema.
Era erro de versão da plataforma do Cordova iOS 6.2.0 que não suportava iOS 16.4 , no GitHub do Cordova iOS  eles soluciona o problema na versão 7.0.0